# Reading all Entities of a Kind

Tags: database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store a couple of million 'rows' into a database and read all of them back for bach processing (stored on disk in json format there is about 200mb of data per million 'rows').

Is GCP datastore suitable for this kind of work? I have a feeling that it might be quite slow when 'table scans' are involved (which is what I'll end up doing).

BigQuery seems like overkill. Would CloudSQL be the best for this kind of work?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery is cheap for storage and querying and fast as well. You can read more in the [pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), or the [post about how to query a terabyte for free each month](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/01/how-to-run-a-terabyte-of-google-bigquery-queries-each-month-without-a-credit-card), for instance. I wouldn't say that it seems overkill for your problem, but I would suggest experimenting with a couple of different backends and see which works best for your needs.